# How to do initialization in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do initialization in ReactJS in a Cordova application. I am somewhat newish to React (this is my first big React project), though not development in general.

I need to do certain events on initialization (Push Notification configuration, analytics, background process setup).

The problem is that for some of these things, I am going to need access to my state store, and specifically my state after login, if the user is logged in (for example, fetching new messages as a background process, which requires a bearer token from my identity provider).

What is the most "React" way to do this? A higher order component to my routing, but below my OIDC provider (keycloak) and store providers? Putting the logic in my login component or "front page" component (both of these seem messy and like anti-patterns to me).

I am guessing the HOC, like so:

```
  <Provider store={store} context={ReactReduxContext}>
    <PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history} context={ReactReduxContext}>
       <Initialization>
        <Layout>
          <Route
          ...
```

This is a React app with Redux and persistent storage.

Any illumination here would be useful.

Comment: I don't see HOC in your example ;)

Comment: <Initialization> here would be the HOC. I can include what I have in it. As far as I can tell, the HOC method worked for me for what I wanted to do. I'm not sure if it is best practices though.